# Where do I put a downloaded package, if I want to use the import keyword? (Java)

Tags: java, package

I downloaded a package from the internet (specifically https://github.com/fusesource/jansi) 

I want to access its classes by using the `import` keyword, just like how you would import java's classes without putting them in the same package. 
I want to do something like:

```
import downloadedPackage.Class;
```

that way, i can access the class without putting it in the same package as my program. Now the problem is, I don't know where to put the downloaded package, such that java would recognize the package if I import it. 

I have searched the net for this but they suggest to put the class in the same package, which is not what i want.

I'm using eclipse btw, thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**  I know that in eclipse, you can add a package, but an IDE independent solution would be great, since we are doing a collab group project in class, and not each of us are using Eclipse. Thanks

Comment: Add it to the classpath

Comment: thanks, but as i said in the edit, i want it to be an IDE independent solution.

Comment: The `classpath` is an IDE-independent concept which an IDE creates a nice GUI interface for. You can still do everything from the command line

Comment: Ohhh, okay thanks for the info! I'm going to do more research now

Comment: This thread should help set your classpath if you want to add a JAR or two: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath

Comment: You can put the library/jar anywhere and just need to put it on the classpath. You might want to look into build systems like Gradle or Maven which can be integrated into all major IDE's as well as work on the command line. Those would make handling dependencies (libraries/"packages") easier.

Comment: Thanks, but one last question tho, If i set my classpath, its true to all projects and not just my current project, right?

Comment: You have to set your classpath for each project you're working on seperately before building/executing

Comment: Bummer, I was hoping the settings would be saved to all. But anyway, thanks! I got this thing working now